# DigitalOcean Spaces / Amazon S3 "InvalidArgument: null at Request.extractError"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

```
InvalidArgument: null
    at Request.extractError (P:\Upwork\MyProject\backend\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\services\s3.js:700:35)
    at Request.callListeners (P:\Upwork\MyProject\backend\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (P:\Upwork\MyProject\backend\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (P:\Upwork\MyProject\backend\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (P:\Upwork\MyProject\backend\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (P:\Upwork\MyProject\backend\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at P:\Upwork\MyProject\backend\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (P:\Upwork\MyProject\backend\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (P:\Upwork\MyProject\backend\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (P:\Upwork\MyProject\backend\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'InvalidArgument',
  region: null,
  time: 2020-12-31T15:39:45.724Z,
  requestId: '',
  extendedRequestId: undefined,
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 85.1667642693943
}
```

This error occurs when trying to upload to DigitalOcean Spaces or Amazon S3.

The error message is very vague just supplying `InvalidArgument` as a reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`code: 'InvalidArgument'` suggests that there is an issue with the supplied `uploadParams`.

```
const uploadParams = {
    Bucket: process.env.DIGITAL_OCEAN_PUBLIC_SPACE_NAME,
    Key: `profile-picture/${userUUID}.jpg`,
    Body: body,
    ACL: 'public',
};
```

In my case we can see above that I was trying to use `ACL: 'public'`.

This is not a valid ACL value, a value of `ACL: 'public-read'` should be used. For private objects you should use `ACL: 'private'`. The documentation can be [found here](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/spaces-api/#access-control-lists-acls).

If you receive this error check that your bucket name, ACL values and all of your uploadParams are valid.